# What does cheat mode do and how can I activate it?

Tags: kittens-game

In Kittens game, there is apparently a cheat mode.

How does one activate cheat mode? What does it let you do? Is there any penalty for activating it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 'real' cheat mode. You'll get this achievement when you click 2500 times in a minute. TO do that, you'll have to use an auto-clicker, which is 'cheating'. [source](http://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/2dr8js/question_regarding_super_unethical_climax/cjs8ui0) (hover over the first 'spoiler' and check the link in the lower left).

You can also read there that there is no real consequence. You'll get the bad achievement, just like:

> Let kittens die

but nothing game-changing happens (right now).

Comment: To illustrate how fast this is: this requires around 42 clicks per second, or once every 24 milliseconds. I'm not sure, but I think most mice will start erroring out at that rate. There's also the biological concern of moving your finger up and down 42 times per second for an entire minute without slowing down. I don't even think nerve endings can send non-reflex signals fast enough for that, let alone that muscles can move at that frequency without damaging themselves.

Comment: You can use the development tool of your browser (F12 i think) and type "gamePage.cheatMode = true;" in the console. I got the achievement like this. But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: "First attempt: 636cpm Second attempt: 750 clicks/minute" - [someone on guiness world records](http://challengers.guinnessworldrecords.com/suggestions/1812)

Answer (score 4):

There is not a cheat mode.  You're most likely referring to the achievement which mentions one; which can be obtained by

> using an autoclicker to gather catnip at inhuman speeds.